# How to dynamically style the host of a component

Tags: css, angular, angular7

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mkcfsd

I have an icon component(app-icon) that dynamically takes a path and inserts the path into an svg viewbox, i get the path's height & width, then set the svg to that height & width. This is so wherever i use the icon, it will align properly. My issue is that the wrapper of app-icon adds 3-4px to the height/width of each icon, i have no idea why. Theres no padding or margin that i can see. (inspect the app-icon element and compare it to its children)

I was thinking it might be best to set the :host equal to the path's width & height. But I haven't found a way to do this dynamically. I've only been able to set styles on the host from my scss file, but unfortunately i can't update these styles dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [@HostBinding](https://angular.io/api/core/HostBinding)

```
@HostBinding('class.my-class') get myClass() {
  return true;
}
```

Comment: How would I set the width and height dynamically?

Comment: @grahamama `@HostBinding('style.width') width = 0;`

Comment: @PatrykUszyński unfortunately this doesn't solve my issue, since the svg path and viewbox arent measured in pixels, when i set the host width/height it is way too big. Any ideas how to make the host the exact dimensions as its children?

Comment: You can set things like `style.width.px` or `style.width.em` to a number, or you can set `style.width` to a string such as `100px`

Comment: @MikeJerred thanks! I've discovered how to set it, but the issue is that when i get the path's width/height, it gives it in viewbox units and not pixels. I'm unsure how to convert this or get the actual pixel dimensions, or how to get the host element to stop adding random pixels to itself